# SQL Query inside a function

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, geospatial

I am using PostgreSQL with PostGis. I am executing a query like this:

```
select st_geomfromtext('point(22 232)',432)
```

It works fine. But now I want to take a value through a query. for example:

```
select st_geomfromtext('point((select x from data_name where id=1) 232)' , 432)
```

Here `data_name` is some table I am using and `x` stores some values. Now query inside is treated as a string and no value is returned.
Please help.

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"
```

Comment: hint: how do you concatenate two strings in postgresql?

Comment: || is used to concatenate the strings but still same error is thrown

Comment: @muratgu using `||` or function: `concat`

Comment: I got it. I used concate instead of || and it worked. Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select st_geomfromtext('point(' || x || ' 232)', 432) from data_name where id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Postgis has a function `ST_MakePoint` that is faster than `ST_GeomFromText`.

```
select ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x),432) from data_name where id=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

While [@muratgu answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15856312/939860) is **generally the way to go**, one minor note:
A subquery gets you a **different result** when no row is found for `id = 1`. Then you get nothing back (no row), instead of:

```
select st_geomfromtext(NULL, 432)
```

If you need a drop-in replacement:

```
select st_geomfromtext('point('
                       || (select x from data_name where id=1)
                       || ' 232)' , 432)
```